# Changes made in hook_node_view() are not applied?

Tags: nodes

I wanted to change the title of a node field on the node display page.

I have implemented `hook_node_view()` and changed the title in code using following code:

```
$node->content['my_field']['#title'] = t('Field Name');
```

When I `dpm()` the `$node` object I can see that above code has been successfully executed, but on node display page I still don't see the field name changed.

I also did a `dpm()` of `$content` from tpl file and found out that `$content['my_field']['#title']` has been set to 'Field Name' as per above code. But it still displays the older title.

Whay may be causing this to happen?

Comment: What is the fields type?

Comment: @FelixEve: It is a select list field

Comment: Could you please post the completed hook implementation code blcok?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have added extra fields in the content variable so you have to override the old title